# Remove space between FieldLabel and Radio Buttons in Ext.net

Tags: c#, html, ext.net, spacing

I am having a problem with the radiogroup FieldLabel because when I dont have the field label in the same column, all the radio buttons are fine and grouped together, but I need the field label to be above all 3 buttons in 1 column. But when i put them in 1 column, all the radio buttons get spaced out. And me and my friend have tried everything to remove the spaces but cant figure it out.

[image: example] [image: example2]

```
                   <ext:Panel ID="Panel1" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Title="Step 1: Choose date span and set spans" 
                        Region="North"
                        Height="200" 
                        Width="400"
                        MinWidth="225" 
                        MaxWidth="400">

                        <Items>
                            <ext:Container runat="server" Layout="RowLayout" Height="200">
                                <Items>
                                    <ext:RadioGroup  runat="server" ID="ChooseSpan" FieldLabel="Choose Date Span" Selectable="true" ColumnsNumber="1" LabelAlign="Top" LabelPad="1">
                                        <Items>
                                            <ext:Radio ID="RadioAll" runat="server" BoxLabel="Show All" InputValue="0" />
                                            <ext:Radio ID="RadioMonth" runat="server" BoxLabel="Choose Date Range(By Month)" InputValue="1" />
                                            <ext:Radio ID="RadioDate" runat="server" BoxLabel="Choose Date Range(By Dates)" InputValue="2" />
                                        </Items>
                                    </ext:RadioGroup>
                                </Items>
                            </ext:Container>
                        </Items>
                    </ext:Panel>
```

Comment: why not put that label in its own `Div` where is the label that says `Choose DateSpan:`

Comment: We tried that, but the font it completely different when we put it in a div or span. We tried using various techniques to change the font that way, but realized there had to be a way to just remove the spaces.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sDSQQ/ ? this good?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce the same results, but the following sample appears to render correctly.

**Example**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:TabPanel 
            runat="server"
            Height="200" 
            Width="400">
            <Items>
                <ext:Panel runat="server" Title="Step 1" Layout="FitLayout">
                    <Items>
                        <ext:Panel runat="server" Title="Step 1: Choose date span and set spans" Layout="FitLayout">
                            <Items>
                                <ext:Container runat="server">
                                    <Items>
                                        <ext:RadioGroup 
                                            runat="server" 
                                            FieldLabel="Choose Date Span" 
                                            Selectable="true" 
                                            ColumnsNumber="1" 
                                            LabelAlign="Top" 
                                            LabelPad="1">
                                            <Items>
                                                <ext:Radio runat="server" BoxLabel="Show All" InputValue="0" />
                                                <ext:Radio runat="server" BoxLabel="Choose Date Range(By Month)" InputValue="1" />
                                                <ext:Radio runat="server" BoxLabel="Choose Date Range(By Dates)" InputValue="2" />
                                            </Items>
                                        </ext:RadioGroup>
                                    </Items>
                                </ext:Container>
                            </Items>
                        </ext:Panel>
                    </Items>

                </ext:Panel>
                <ext:Panel runat="server" Title="Step 2" />
            </Items>
        </ext:TabPanel> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```